# print the value selected in recycleview kivy

Tags: python, android-recyclerview, kivy

I have a problem, when pressing on the list of the recyclerview i print the number of the index but i need print the value in the index code in below
please any one can help me

```
class SecondWindow(BoxLayout,Screen):
    myresult = ListProperty([("N_matricule", "Operateur")])

    def insert_part(self):
        partnum = self.ids.Part_field
        part = partnum.text

        mycursor.execute(
            """SELECT OPERATION_DESCRIPTION FROM liste_des_operations WHERE PART_NO = %s""",
            (part,))
        self.myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
        #for row in myresult:
            #print(row)
            #print(type(row))
class RVItem(Factory.Button):
    def get_data_index(self, values):
        return self.parent.get_view_index_at(self.center)
    def on_press(self):
        print(self.get_data_index())
```

kv file

```
RecycleView:

    data: [{'text':"{}".format(OPERATION_DESCRIPTION)} for OPERATION_DESCRIPTION in root.myresult]
    viewclass: "RVItem"
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        orientation: "vertical"
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        key_selection: 'selectable'
        multiselect: True
        touch_multiselect: True
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to print the text that is shown on the `Button`? If so, you can just `print(self.text)` in your `on_press()` method.

Comment: can you explain what you want to print? I can propably help you as I played around with the recycleview the last days, but I dont get what you want to print.

Comment: thanks John Anderson  , It's worked now when I added print(self.text) in my on_press()

Comment: thanks MisterNox for help it's work now