# print the value selected from the recycleview

Tags: python, android-recyclerview, kivy

I have a problem, when pressing on the list of the recyclerview i print the number of the index but i need print the value in the index code in below please any one can help me

```
class SecondWindow(BoxLayout,Screen):
myresult = ListProperty([("N_matricule", "Operateur")])

    def insert_part(self):
        partnum = self.ids.Part_field
        part = partnum.text

        mycursor.execute(
        """SELECT OPERATION_DESCRIPTION FROM liste_des_operations WHERE PART_NO = %s""",
        (part,))
        self.myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
    #for row in myresult:
        #print(row)
        #print(type(row))
class RVItem(Factory.Button):
    def get_data_index(self, values):
        return self.parent.get_view_index_at(self.center)
    def on_press(self):
        print(self.get_data_index())
```

kv file

```
RecycleView:

                data: [{'text':"{}".format(OPERATION_DESCRIPTION)} for OPERATION_DESCRIPTION in root.myresult]
                viewclass: "RVItem"
                RecycleBoxLayout:
                    default_size: None, dp(56)
                    orientation: "vertical"
                    default_size_hint: 1, None
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    key_selection: 'selectable'
                    multiselect: True
                    touch_multiselect: True
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIClV.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [print the value selected in recycleview kivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61563477/print-the-value-selected-in-recycleview-kivy)

Comment: yes John Anderson many thanks